# Tensorflow docker, what is difference between NGC image and Docker Hub image?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, nvidia, dockerhub

What are the differences between the [official Tensorflow image on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/) and the [Tensorflow image on NVIDIA NGC](https://ngc.nvidia.com/catalog/containers/nvidia:tensorflow)?

I just want to train my model with both tf1/2. NGC images are so huge and both are working well. I don't see any difference between them. Wondering why there are two duplicated repository.

Comment: Difference is Tensorflow image on NVIDIA NGC supports NVIDIA GPU version of Tensorflow and Tensorflow docker image supports CPU and GPU versions of Tensorflow. Thanks!